# How to create JSON in android with multiple data

Tags: php, android, json

I've to create in android like this,

```
"draft":
 [
  { "firstName": "Glen", "lastName": "McGrath" },
  { "firstName": "Steve", "lastName": "Vaugh" }
 ]
```

How can I create this type of JSON? I've been through some links but not getting correct output.

So far, I've tried this code,

```
JSONObject newObj = null ;              
                for(int h=0; h<3; h++)
                {
                    newObj = new JSONObject();
                    newObj.put("firstName", "" + h);
                    newObj.put("lastName", "" + h);
                }

                JSONArray postjson = new JSONArray();
                postjson.put(newObj);
```

But, not getting any output while decoding this json in php file.

Below is my .php file to decode json,

```
$json = $_SERVER['HTTP_JSON'];
$json = json_decode($json, true);
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
mysql_select_db("retail_menu") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
    foreach($json as $value)
    {

        foreach($value as $value1)
        {
            echo $data1 = $value1['firstName'];
            echo $data2 = $value1['lastName'];

            $query = "INSERT INTO `rr_friendid` (friend_id, friend_name) VALUES ('$data1','$data2')";
        var_dump($query);
        mysql_query($query);
    }

}
```

But, I can't see any values store in database. I don't know where I'm wrong, in creating json or while decoding it. How can I create json as the above I mentioned?

Comment: Have a look at GSON it is able to generate a JSON from a JAVA Object.

Comment: Have you tried echoing out what you get to begin with in the PHP? I've never seen `$_SERVER['HTTP_JSON']` before, so I'm not sure about that. Are you not trying to post it i.e. `$_POST`?

Comment: @JonathonHenderson: I tried to decode json with single data json.put("name", "MSD" ); json.put("position", "Bhatiya"); and in php I get this using $json = $_SERVER['HTTP_JSON']; and it's working...

Comment: Are you getting the expected JSON string when you echo out `$json` (Before decoding it)? Should hopefully be: `{"draft":[{"firstName":"Glen","lastName":"McGrath"},{"firstName":"Steve","lastName":"Vaugh"}]}`. Also are you getting the expected array after decoding it? Use `var_dump`

Comment: Also, have you tried using `json_last_error()` to ensure it's decoding properly? http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: actually I am running this .php file from my android code...

Answer (score 0):

The following json you require is not valid:

```
"draft":
 [
  { "firstName": "Glen", "lastName": "McGrath" },
  { "firstName": "Steve", "lastName": "Vaugh" }
 ]
```

It should have an enclosing braze.

```
{
    "draft": [
        {
            "firstName": "Glen",
            "lastName": "McGrath"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Steve",
            "lastName": "Vaugh"
        }
    ]
}
```

To check valid json format, see [onlineJsonEditor.](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/)